# How to iterate through paginated results in the Python SDK for Microsoft Graph?

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm getting to grips with the [Python SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python), having never used GraphQL before (but I'm familiar with the basic concept). I'm able to retrieve the `odata_next_link` value from responses, but I'm not sure how to use it. I note from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging) that:

> You should include the entire URL in the @odata.nextLink property in your request for the next page of results. Depending on the API that the query is being performed against, the @odata.nextLink URL value will contain either a $skiptoken or a $skip query parameter. The URL also contains all the other query parameters present in the original request. Do not try to extract the $skiptoken or $skip value and use it in a different request.

However, I'm not sure *how* to include that URL in the next request. Currently, my queries look like `response = await graph_client.groups.by_group_id(group_id).transitive_members.get()` - I don't see an option there to change the base url. I thought I could do something like:

```
query_params = GroupsRequestBuilder.GroupsRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
  skip_token = parse_qs(urlparse(response.odata_next_link).query)['$skipToken'][0]
)
request_configuration = GroupsRequestBuilder.GroupsRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(
  query_parameters=query_params
)
response = await graph_client.[...].get(request_configuration)
```

but that reports `GroupsRequestBuilder.GroupsRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skip_token'` (and similarly for if I try naming the parameter `skiptoken` or `skipToken`)

Frustratingly, there's no code example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp) - but, based on those examples, I did search the repo for an Iterator - [with no results](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoftgraph%2Fmsgraph-sdk-python%20iterator&type=code).

Comment: Other SDKs for Graph API have page iterator, but according to [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python/issues/105) page iterator for python SDK is not implemented. There is a working example for [Groups](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python/issues/105#:~:text=request_info.url%20%3D%20....-,Working%20Example,-If%20anyone%20else)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We do not have a page iterator for the Python SDK yet, however there is added support for using a raw url for the request. In the case of pagination, a user can use the **odata_next_link** property value to make a fresh request using **with_url** and get items in the next page.

Here's a working example:

```py
from msgraph.generated.users.users_request_builder import UsersRequestBuilder

async def get_users():

    query_params = UsersRequestBuilder.UsersRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(

    select=["id", "displayName", "createdDateTime"],

    top=5,

    )

    request_config = UsersRequestBuilder.UsersRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(

        query_parameters=query_params

    )

    users_list = []

    users = await client.users.get(request_configuration=request_config)

    for user in users.value:

        users_list.append(user)

    next_link = users.odata_next_link

    while next_link:

        users = await client.users.with_url(next_link).get()

        next_link = users.odata_next_link

        for user in users.value:

            users_list.append(user)

    print(len(users_list))
```